# Socket remains in CLOSE_WAIT state

Tags: c, windows, wininet

I am using Wininet to perform a check with my server when the application get started.

The problem is that after calling CloseInternetHandle the socket state remains CLOSE_WAIT as seen on netstat, and the worst part is that it never changes it state.

Here is the simple code I am using. What am I doing wrong ?

```
hInternet = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNETOPENTYPEPRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (hInternet)
    {
        hFile = InternetOpenUrl(hInternet, url, NULL, 0, INTERNETFLAGRELOAD, 0);

        InternetReadFile(hFile, &buffer, 20, &btsRead);
        InternetCloseHandle(hFile);
        InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
    }
```

Comment: How long are you waiting before declaring that it "never" changes?

Comment: Is the app running or is the debugger paused? CLOSE_WAIT means that the app hasn't yet closed the socket.

Comment: But I am closing it as you can see, it's not running inside a debugger.

Comment: You are not closing the TCP connection. You are closing the internet handle. The WinInet APIs surely support HTTP keep-alive and connection pooling. Pausing the debugger prevents cleanup.

Comment: @usr it's not running in a debugger as I said before and how can I close the TCP Connection ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinInet tries to re-use sockets where it can, so even when you release the handle it can choose to keep the socket active, ready for the next call to InternetOpen. Most of the time this is a good thing and you don't need to worry about it.

It is not a handle leak. You can see this if you put your code in a loop and look at the local port number in netstat: the same socket is getting reused over and over again. When your process finishes, the socket will be closed properly by WinInet.

If you **really** need it to be closed immediately, you can fool WinInet into doing this by calling InternetSetOption after your final InternetCloseHandle:

```
...
InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
InternetSetOption(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_SETTINGS_CHANGED, NULL, 0);
```

Doing this tells WinInet that global WinInet settings have changed (e.g. in the Registry) so it has no choice but to close all sockets and reset itself. However this obviously is not the intended usage and will have some performance impact if you are making lots of connections with WinInet.